# NextgenSplunk: Need help forming a splunk query which takes sessionId from a particular set of logs, use it to form next query

Tags: splunk

I need to form a Splunk query to find a particular sessionId for which log a is available but log b is not. Both are part of the same transaction but code breaking in between somewhere.

> LOGGER.info("Log a:: setting some details in session");
>
> Response response = handler.transactionMethod(token); //throws some exception
>
> LOGGER.info("Log b:: getting details in session");

So in the success scenario, both Log a and Log b will be printed. But when transactionMethod throws an exception, only Log a will be printed for that sessionId and not Log b.

The requirement is I need to find any of the sessionId for which only Log a is present, not Log b.

Comment: Is there anything in the messages that links Log a to Log b?  A session ID, perhaps?  Possible solutions depend on the answer.

Comment: You mention `SessionID` but I do not see this field on you data sample. Can you add it (using [Edit])?

Comment: @PM77-1 SessionID will be there by default for each log. Unique for each session.

Comment: @RichG So Log a is where we set something in session, (session.setAttribute()) and at Log b trying to fetch the same thing back from the session. But if the code breaks in between, this flow will never reach log b and those are the flows I'm trying to identify.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have 2 fields `TEXT` and `SessionID` already defined, we will use the following test data:

```
SessionID=1001 TEXT="setting
SessionID=1001 TEXT="getting
SessionID=1002 TEXT="setting
SessionID=1003 TEXT="getting"
```

Splunk query:

````
| makeresults count=4
| streamstats count
| eval TEXT=case(count=1 OR count=3, "setting", count=2 OR count=4, "getting")
| eval SessionID=case(count=1 OR count=2, 1001, count=3, 1002, count=4, 1003)
   ``` The above is just setting of the test data ```
   ``` Below is the actual SPL for the task ```
| stats count(eval(TEXT=setting")) as LogA count(eval(TEXT="getting") as Logb by SessionID
| search LogA > 0 and LogB = 0
````

As you can see I specifically excluded the case when only "LogB" record is present (SessionID=3)